# Mac OS X - read always return 1

Tags: c, macos, posix

I'm currently writing a C program that writes to the serial port on Mac OS X. I would like to use the Posix API to use the code on Gnu/Linux as well. I read the 'Posix Serial Programming' to configure the serial port and write basic read/write commands. the programm is the following :

```
//
//  main.c
//  navilink
//
//  Created by HEINRICH Yannick on 22/11/2013.
//
//

#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include "packetapi.h"

int main (){


    int fd;

    fd = open("/dev/tty.usbserial", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY |O_NDELAY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Unable to open port !");
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,0);
    }

    struct termios options;

    tcgetattr(fd, &options);

    cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);

    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);


    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);


    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    options.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

   unsigned char * packet = YGCreatePacket(PID_SYNC, 0, 0);

   write(fd, packet, 9);


    unsigned char buffer[255], *ptrBuffer;

    ptrBuffer = buffer;
    ssize_t nbytes = 0;
    while((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - ptrBuffer -1) > 0))
    {
        ptrBuffer += nbytes;
        if(ptrBuffer[-1] == PACK_END2 && ptrBuffer[-2] == PACK_END1)
            break;
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;

}
```

I have a strange behavior on my OS (Mavericks), at this part :

```
 unsigned char buffer[255], *ptrBuffer;

    ptrBuffer = buffer;
    ssize_t nbytes = 0;
    while((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - ptrBuffer -1) > 0))
    {
        ptrBuffer += nbytes;
        if(ptrBuffer[-1] == PACK_END2 && ptrBuffer[-2] == PACK_END1)
            break;
    }
```

When I use the debugger, the `nbytes`variable is always `1` but when I look into the `buffer`array at the same time, it is filled with more than 1 byte, `read`seems to not return the number of bytes read...

What is wrong with this approach ?

Comment: `read(fd, buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - ptrBuffer -1)` should be `read(fd, ptrBuffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - ptrBuffer -1)`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead (only one paren changed place - I'm assuming the pointer arithmetics is valid):

```
while((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - ptrBuffer -1)) > 0)
```

With your code, you're storing the result of the comparison into `nbytes`, and that'll always be 0 or 1.

Comment: And the second argument should be `bufferPtr`, not `buffer`, as commented above.

Comment: I feel so stupid right know :) Thanks for revealing me this huge mistake !